# Notepad++ Как оставить только нужный кусок в строчке?

Tags: notepad++

Есть следующие строчки:

```
"Бензиновый генератор Hyundai HHY 3020F (2800 Вт)";"бензиновый";"ручной";...
"Бензиновый генератор Hyundai HHY 3020FE (2800 Вт)";"бензиновый";"электрический, ручной"...
"Газо-бензиновый генератор СПЕЦ HG-2700 (2200 Вт)";"газо-бензиновый";"ручной"...
"Бензиновый генератор Kronwerk KB 3500 (3000 Вт)";"бензиновый";"ручной"...
```

Как правильно составить регулярное выражение, чтобы выходные были следующие:

```
"Hyundai HHY 3020F";"бензиновый";"ручной";...
"Hyundai HHY 3020FE";"бензиновый";"электрический, ручной"...
"СПЕЦ HG-2700";"газо-бензиновый";"ручной"...
"Kronwerk KB 3500";"бензиновый";"ручной"...
```

При использование - **^"[А-Яа-я\s-]+**

Получается следующее:

```
> Hyundai HHY 3020F (2800 Вт)";"бензиновый";"ручной";... 
> Hyundai HHY 3020FE (2800 Вт)";"бензиновый";"электрический, ручной"... 
> HG-2700 (2200 Вт)";"газо-бензиновый";"ручной"... 
> Kronwerk KB 3500 (3000 Вт)";"бензиновый";"ручной"...
```

Пропали **"** и концовки не убрались. 
Также у третьего пункта пропало название в связи с RU названием товара.

Я буду чрезмерно благодарен вам за помощь! Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё что в **()** удаляется

```
\([^)]+\)
```

Начало строк **убирай через стандартную замену**, это просто))

Comment: Спасибо! Работает!